# ActionLink builds wrong URL when using System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I'm using MVC 5 and I'm trying to get the routing done via `System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute`.

So the most actions do work, one doesn't.

I created a `Delete`-action and an `Edit`-action. Both look the same.

Here the `Delete`-method:

```
[Route("data/links/delete/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
{
    // ....
    return View(link);
}

// in the view, DeleteConfirmed is called on submit

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("data/links/delete/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    // ....
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here the `Edit`-method:

```
[Route("data/links/edit/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    // ....
    return View(link);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("data/links/edit")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,LinkText,Url,Image,Description")] Link link)
{
    // ....
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So, the routing of them both looks the same. 
The links I call them `GET`-methods are the same too:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Bearbeiten", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
@Html.ActionLink("Löschen", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
```

Funny thing is:

```
the link to edit gets rendered: http://localhost:45132/data/links/edit?id=2
the link to delete gets rendered: http://localhost:45132/data/links/delete/2
```

Why is edit rendered to `edit?id=2` and delete to `delete/2`?

The edit-link doesn't work. When I manually enter the edit-page at http://localhost:45132/data/links/edit/2 then the link works. 
But ActionLink gets me a wrong URL. Any idea?

**update**

My RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: @SeM added RouteConfig.cs

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Yeah, Did not look at it careful enough. Maybe it is picking up the route from the post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **[RouteLink helper method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd470133(v=vs.118))** instead.

Define `Name` property to your `Route` attribute, for example:

```
[Route("data/links/edit/{id}", Name = "MyRoute")]
```

then use:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Bearbeiten", "MyRoute", new { id = item.Id })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving as designed. You have a complex model in the edit, which is also not part of the route template. so it has to put the properties provided when generating the link in the query string.

To get the desired routes...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("data/links/edit/{id:int}")] // GET data/links/edit/2
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id) {
    // ....
    return View(link);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("data/links/edit/{id:int}")] // POST data/links/edit/2
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind(Include = "Id,LinkText,Url,Image,Description")] Link link) {
    // ....
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Ah I need to add the id as parameter in the POST that the GET is called...?! I see... I stick with SeMs answer. Looks cleaner to me